# Emailing an Android deep link with a custom protocol?

Tags: android, react-native

I've set up [deep linking](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking) on my android app built with React Native with links like `myapp://open/foo`. The links work fine in via email on the iOS version of the app, and I've tested them on Android with `adb`:

```
$>adb shell am start -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "myapp://open/users/123" com.myapp.foo
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW . 
dat=myapp://open/users/123 pkg=com.myapp.foo }
Status: ok...
```

Test links I sent via email simply aren't recognized by the Android mail app and Gmail app. They show up as untappable links. I'm using standard html link syntax:

```
 <a href="myapp://open/foo">open app</a>
```

All the regular links in the email are tappable. Is there a trick to sending them? Do I need to use [Android App Links instead](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-site-associations)?